# R forecast output to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I am doing database analysis using SQL Server and forecasting using R.  I need to get the results from R back into the SQL Server database.  One approach is to output the forecast data to a text file using write.table and import using BULK INSERT.  Is there a better way?

Comment: You should be able to do this directly with `RODBC` or a similar package - take a look at [this help page](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RODBC/docs/sqlUpdate).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dbBulkCopy` from [`rsqlserver`](https://github.com/agstudy/rsqlserver) package. It is a DBI extension that interfaces the Microsoft SQL Server popular command-line utility named **bcp** to quickly bulk copying large files into table.

```
dat <- matrix(round(rnorm(nrow * ncol), 2), nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol)
colnames(dat) <- cnames
id.file = "temp_file.csv"
write.csv(dat, file = id.file, row.names = FALSE)
dbBulkCopy(conn, "NEW_BP_TABLE", value = id.file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments and answers!  I went with a solution based on the comment by nrussell.  Below is my code.  The specific command is the last line; I am providing the preceding lines to provide a little bit of context for anyone trying to use this answer.

```
data <- sqlQuery(myconn, query) # returns time series with year, month (both numeric), and value
data_ts <- ts(data$value, 
              start=c(data$year[1],data$month[1]), # start is first year and month
              end=c(data$year[nrow(data)],data$month[nrow(data)]), # end is last year and month
              frequency=12)
data_fit <- auto.arima(data_ts)
fct <- forecast(data_ts, 12)
sqlQuery(myconn, 'truncate table dgtForecast') # Pre-existing table
sqlSave(myconn, data.frame(fct), tablename='dgtForecast', rownames='MonthYear', append=TRUE)
```